# Why are multiple model files created in gensim word2vec?

Tags: python, word2vec, gensim, word-embedding

When I try to create a word2vec model (skipgram with negative sampling) I received 3 files as output as follows.

```
word2vec (File)
word2vec.syn1nef.npy (NPY file)
word2vec.wv.syn0.npy (NPY file)
```

I am just worried why this happens as for my previous test examples in word2vec I only received one model(no npy files).

Please help me.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Models with larger internal vector-arrays can't be saved via Python 'pickle' to a single file, so beyond a certain threshold, the gensim `save()` method will store subsidiary arrays in separate files, using the more-efficient raw format of numpy arrays (`.npy` format).

You still `load()` the model by just specifying the root model filename; when the subsidiary arrays are needed, the loading code will find the side files – as long as they're kept beside the root file. So when moving a model elsewhere, be sure to keep all files with the same root filename together.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer :)

Comment: Can you point me towards what exactly are stored individually in the files?

Comment: You should consult the source code for that information: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/word2vec.py & https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py will show what `syn1neg`, `syn0`, and other other properties that might be stored as separate files are.