# Suffixes being added to extra model files during save

Tags: python-2.7, gensim

When I execute the below code

```
sim_model = gensim.similarities.MatrixSimilarity(corp)
sim_model.save("sim_model.pkl")
```

Instead of getting "sim_model.pkl" I get two files "sim_model.pkl.index.npy" and "sim_model.pkl" why is this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For larger models, a single `save()` can result in multiple files being written, with extra suffixes. See [Why are multiple model files created in gensim word2vec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47173538/why-are-multiple-model-files-created-in-gensim-word2vec) for more details.